# asp net core Update Model in Jquery

Tags: jquery, .net-core

In my ASP.Net Core 2.2 app I have a Page model. This model has a property, for instance:

```
public string filter { get; set; }
```

In my CSHTML file I transfer this to javascript, like this:

```
var filter = @Html.Raw(Json.Serialize(Model.fiter));
```

The `filter` variable in my JS has the correct value. However I would like to give this `filter` variable a different `value` and reload the page.

```
filter = newvalue; //some string
location.reload(true);
```

I would expect to get the `filter` value back in my page model but, the page is reloading but the filter value of my model is not updated. What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 0):

`location.reload` sends a GET request without the value of your JavaScript data `filter`.

To send that data, you can

- include it in a `input` of a `form` and simulates the submission of the form; it will issue a POST request with the form's data
- navigate to an URL such as `www.website.com/page?filter=value`; you'll need to change the signature of controller's action to take `filter` as parameter